# NavigationLink skips to one specific navigation, no menu screen - also, Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a navigation screen with two buttons for two view controllers.

I [found a game online](https://github.com/caiobzen/2048-swiftui) which has similar navigation implemented. But when I run it, it takes me straight to the first navigation item without showing the options screen.

I want to get the navigation working properly, but it does not.

Note: I'm getting an error on the second part (GameViewController.swift) on line 9 saying `Argument passed to call that takes no arguments`. It seems I need to move `viewModel` or something similar into `ContentView` but the different ways I've tried just pop up more errors that I don't understand.

```
    import SwiftUI
    import Foundation
    
    // I think I need to reference viewModel below somehow, but I'm just not sure how
    // I tried different ways but just always get more errors I don't understand yet
    struct ContentView: View {
        @State private var score = 0
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                Image("Clouds")
                    .overlay(
                    VStack(spacing: 30) {
                        NavigationLink(destination: ResultView2(choice: "MenuGrey")) {
                                Image("MenuGrey")
                        }
                        NavigationLink(destination: MyContentView(viewModel: GameViewModel(Engine.self as! Engine, storage: Storage.self as! Storage, stateTracker: StateTracker.self as! StateTracker))) {
                                Image("Menu")
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
    }
    
    struct MyContentView: View {
        @ObservedObject var viewModel: GameViewModel
        @State var showMenu = false
        var body: some View {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 16) {
                Header(score: viewModel.state.score, bestScore: viewModel.bestScore, menuAction: {
                    self.showMenu.toggle()
                }, undoAction: {
                    self.viewModel.undo()
                }, undoEnabled: self.viewModel.isUndoable)
                GoalText()
                Board(board: viewModel.state.board, addedTile: viewModel.addedTile)
                Moves(viewModel.numberOfMoves)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: .zero,
                   maxWidth: .infinity,
                   minHeight: .zero,
                   maxHeight: .infinity,
                   alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.gameBackground)
                .background(Menu())
                .background(GameOver())
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
    extension MyContentView {
    private func Menu() -> some View {
        EmptyView().sheet(isPresented: $showMenu) {
            MenuView(newGameAction: {
                self.viewModel.reset()
                self.showMenu.toggle()
            }, resetScoreAction: {
                self.viewModel.eraseBestScore()
                self.showMenu.toggle()
            })
        }
    }
    
    private func GameOver() -> some View {
        EmptyView().sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.isGameOver) {
            GameOverView(score: self.viewModel.state.score, moves: self.viewModel.numberOfMoves) {
                self.viewModel.reset()
            }
        }
    }
    }
    
    struct ResultView2: View {
        var choice: String
        var body: some View {
            Text("You chose MenuGrey")
        }
    }
```

The below is the GameViewController.swift part

```
    import SwiftUI
    import Foundation
    
    class GameViewController: UIHostingController<ContentView> {
        private let viewModel: GameViewModel?
        
        init(viewModel: GameViewModel) {
            self.viewModel = viewModel
            super.init(rootView: ContentView(viewModel: viewModel))
            // The line above gives error "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"
            
            setupGestures()
    
            viewModel.start()
        }
            
        private func setupGestures() {
            view.addGestureRecognizer(Swipe(.left) { [weak self] in
                self?.viewModel?.push(.left)
            })
            view.addGestureRecognizer(Swipe(.right) { [weak self] in
                self?.viewModel?.push(.right)
            })
            view.addGestureRecognizer(Swipe(.up) { [weak self] in
                self?.viewModel?.push(.up)
            })
            view.addGestureRecognizer(Swipe(.down) { [weak self] in
                self?.viewModel?.push(.down)
            })
        }
        
        @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does adding `@ObservedObject var viewModel: GameViewModel` to your `ContentView` helps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, that `error` is saying that you are trying to pass something to the `ContentView` (in this case you are passing an instance of `GameViewModel` while the `ContentView` does not expect that thing (in this case that instance), So to fix that we have to make the `ContentView` to take an instance of `GameViewModel`.
According to the code and explanation you provided, you need to do few things to fix correctly the error:

***1. Create an instance variable of `GameViewModel` in your `ContentView`:***

Add this in your ContentView

```
static let engine = GameEngine()
static let storage = LocalStorage()
static let stateTracker = GameStateTracker(initialState: (storage.board ?? engine.blankBoard, storage.score))
@ObservedObject var viewModel =  GameViewModel(engine, storage: storage, stateTracker: stateTracker)
```

***2. Change the `NavigationLink` in your `ContentView`:***

Change

```
NavigationLink(destination: MyContentView(viewModel: GameViewModel(Engine.self as! Engine, storage: Storage.self as! Storage, stateTracker: StateTracker.self as! StateTracker))) {
    Image("Menu")
}
```

to

```
NavigationLink(destination: MyContentView(viewModel: viewModel)) {
    Image("Menu")
}
```

At this stage, the `error` should be gone.

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much! I wish I had 15 reputation so I could click the up arrow vote thing, but I appreciate the information. I learn best by doing and learning from mistakes, so the information combined with -why- it's that way is extremely helpful.